# How to make characters appear in the correct order in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, duplicates

I have a C program which is meant to return the repeating characters and their frequencies from a given input string. At the moment, it works fine, however I was wondering if there was a way I  could change it so it would return characters in order of appearance, as opposed to alphabetical(?) order.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
# define NO_OF_CHARS 256

char fillCharCounts(unsigned char *str, int *count)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
      count[*(str+i)]++;
return 0;
}

void printDups(unsigned char *str)
{
  int *count = (int *)calloc(NO_OF_CHARS,
                             sizeof(int));
  fillCharCounts(str, count);


int dupe_chars = 0; 
int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++)
        if (count[i] > 1) {
            printf ("\nDuplicate letter: %c, Occurrences: %d", i, count[i]);
            ++dupe_chars; 
        }

    if (0 != dupe_chars)
        printf ("\n");        
    else
        printf ("\nNo duplicates found\n");

  free(count);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char str[15] = "";
    printf("Enter a word>");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printDups(str);
    getchar();

return 0;
}
```

At the moment, if the input string were say "zzbbaa" it would give the output;

"Duplicate: a, count: 2"
"Duplicate: b, count: 2"
"Duplicate: z, count: 2"

How can I change this so the output returns the duplicates in order of appearance in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the string again, printing out the duplicate the first time it's found.

Here's code as I would write it. There's no need for dynamic allocation of memory -- the `count` array can go on the stack, and `*(str + i)` is much better written `str[i]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void printDups(unsigned char *s) {
    int count[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};
    int dupes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        count[s[i]]++;
        dupes = dupes || (count[s[i]] > 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (count[s[i]] > 1) {
            printf("Duplicate letter: %c, Occurrences: %d\n", s[i], count[s[i]]);
            count[s[i]] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!dupes) {
        printf("No duplicates found\n");
    }
 }

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    unsigned char s[] = "hello world";
    printDups(s);
}
```